# Add drop down list attribute to category - set source

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I added  "brand" attribute (drop down list) for products.
I'm trying add new attribute (drop down list) to category with values from "brand" attribute.
What should I do to set correct source for this category attribute.
Please see my piece of code in mysql setup file:

```
    $this->startSetup();
    $this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'brand', array(
    'group'                => 'General',
    'type'              => 'int'
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend_input'    => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'brand',
    'input'             => 'select'
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'mymodule/selecattributes',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'frontend_class'    => '',
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'position'          => 100,
));
$this->endSetup();
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**
I added class MyPackage_MyModule_Model_SelectAttributes extends extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract :

```
class MyPackage_MyModule_Model_SelectAttributes extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $attributeCode = 'brand';

        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode); //here, "color" is the attribute_code
        $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
        foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
            $myArray[$instance['value']] = $instance['label'];
        }

        return $myArray;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
When I open category admin page I get this error:

```
"Source model "mymodule/selectattributes" not found for attribute "brands""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your source model is in a file named *`Selectattributes.php`*.  If you are using a case-sensitive filesystem you will need to do one of two things:

- Rename your class definition file to *`Selectattributes.php`*

  *or*
- Change the `source_model` value for your **brands** attribute to `mymodule/selectAttributes`

When Magento is attempting to instantiate the source model for your attribute, the classname (and hence the autoload include path) being calculated work as follows:

```
MyPackage_MyModule_Model_Selectattributes
MyPackage/MyModule/Model/Selectattributes.php
```

Note the issue with the filename. Note that this *should* be working in a non-case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: You were right :) I changed value for source_model for mymodule/SelectAttributes and now it's works good. Many thanks :)